# Handling named parameters in R

Tags: r

So R seems different than a lot of other languages in that you can pass parameters to functions in any order you like provided that you name them.  But you can also pass parameters that are not actually required by the function since a subfunction might require those.  For example consider:

```
predict(glm.fit, data.test, type="response")
```

you can also call

```
predict(glm.fit, type="response", newdata=data.test)
```

since here `newdata` is identified by name rather than position. However it is incredibly easy and deadly to accidentally write

```
predict(glm.fit, type="response", data=data.test)
```

which will not raise an error, but in this case it ignores the validation set `data.test` and uses the original because the parameter is called data rather than newdata and it thinks it is a supplemental parameter.

My question - How do people avoid this really easy to make but incredibly difficult to find error?  It took me hours to figure out why my test error was so high, and it was a fluke that I noticed it at all.  Do you just avoid naming parameters?

Comment: Are you using any sort of IDE or specialized editor (RStudio, Visual Studio, Emacs...)?

Comment: ....you can also observe that the number of predictions will be equal to the number of rows of your train set and not your test set. Unless you have exactly the same number of rows. Unfortunately `predict(..., data=...)` doesn't return any error or warning.

Comment: I use a mix of naming and not naming depending on the functions and how intuitive that function is to me. Basically if I use the function in a standard way and I am familiar with it I wont specify the names. For predict I don't usually specify names.  I use R studio which also suggests standard names. I also check basic quality output with the number of observations returned, and NAs etc..

Comment: I do use RStudio, so I guess I should have paid attention to the suggestion.  I just wish there was a setting or something to protect myself from this really easy mistake to make.  I'll try and remember in the future to ensure that the validation and training set have different numbers and then do a basic quality check.  Thanks for the responses everyone.